# Sorting output of dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, stata

My data looks like this:

*(sassign is the data.frame that holds the data)*

```
head(sassign %>% select(child,youth,cook,do_it))
  child youth cook do_it
1     3     2    2     0
2     0     1    0     1
3     0     0    2     0
4     0     0    0     0
5     0     0    1     0
6     0     1    0     0
```

My objective is to find total # of people who bought child books, youth books, cook books and do_it books.

So, here's what I did:

```
sassign %>%  summarise( sumchild=sum(child),sumyouth=sum(youth),sumcook=sum(cook),sumdo_it=sum(do_it))
```

Here's the output I got:

```
  sumchild sumyouth sumcook sumdo_it
1    42723    19549   46830    23153
```

**Question 1:: This solves my purpose, but is there anyway I can get a sorted column-wise output? Here's what I got from Stata:**

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    | Total Std. Err. [95% Conf. Interval]
    -------------+------------------------------------------------
    cook | 46830 265.0706 46310.46 47349.54 
   child | 42723 250.4739 42232.07 43213.93
    do_it | 23153 171.2552 22817.34 23488.66
    youth | 19549 152.7226 19249.66 19848.34
```

As you can see above, STATA output is nicely sorted from top to bottom.

**Question 2:: Is there anyway I can also include SD, and CI as STATA shows?**

**Questions 3:: Is there anyway I can sort on SD, or CI instead of sum in R? I looked at describe function, but I wasn't sure so I thought of asking them here itself.**

I am transitioning from Stata to R, so I would be grateful for any help I can get. I also looked through other posts on SO, but most of them deal with ordering when using group_by.

Thanks

Comment: Use sort?    sassign %>%  summarise( sumchild=sum(child),sumyouth=sum(youth),sumcook=sum(cook),sumdo_it=sum(do_it)) %>%sort(,decreasing = T)

Comment: Thanks biomiha. This helps. However, do you know if I can include SD and CI? One way is to use SD() in summarise, but then I would need 500 SD if I have a lot of variables. Any thoughts?

Comment: See `summarise_all`/`summarise_each` for calculating many stats for many columns.

Comment: What I would do is transform from wide to long format first using gather(). Then I would use group_by()%>%summarise(mean(value), sd(value), etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop through your data, calculate the statistics, put them into a data frame and then rbind them, the sort part can be done using the `arrange` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, function(col) { 
    t.result = t.test(col); 
    data.frame(SUM = sum(col), SD = sd(col), 
               CIL = t.result$conf.int[1], CIH = t.result$conf.int[2]) })) %>% 
    add_rownames(var = "CAT") %>% arrange(desc(SUM))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]

#     CAT   SUM        SD        CIL      CIH
#   <chr> <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  cook     5 0.9831921 -0.1984635 1.865130
# 2 youth     4 0.8164966 -0.1901939 1.523527
# 3 child     3 1.2247449 -0.7852909 1.785291
# 4  doit     1 0.4082483 -0.2617636 0.595097
```